# Searching for files with os.walk if no files are found matching the search criteria- Python

Tags: python, regex, os.walk

Right now I am using os.walk to recursively search directories and subdirectories for any autorun.inf file. I know I'm not doing it in the best way so if you have a better way for that too, please let me know. If it finds anything matching autorun it will output the file's contents for each file found matching the criteria.
However when I try to make an else statement for if no files were found that matched, it prints "No file matching the criteria found" for each file that doesn't match instead of only one time if that makes sense. I only want it to say it once if no file matching the criteria is found. 
Here's what I have so far.

```
import os
from os.path import join
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('/home/user/Documents/mystuff'):
    for filename in files:
    if filename.startswith('autorun'):
        thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
        f = open(thefile)
        print f.read()
    else:
        print "No file matched the criteria"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
found = False

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('/home/user/Documents/mystuff'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.startswith('autorun'):
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
            f = open(thefile)
            print f.read()
            found = True

if not found:
    print "No file matched the criteria"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!